# Dropbox for new standard user not working

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

I've added a new Standard user to my up-to-date Trusty 64-bit, logged in as that user, and invoked Dropbox (from the Dash). The Dropbox wizard says that I'm using old version & should upgrade to a new version downloadable from Dropbox web site. Given that I have had `nautilus-dropbox` installed and my (first) Administrator user has been using Dropbox Ok for years this seems nonsensical. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the `.deb` from the Dropbox site & installed it. I then switched to my second user. When the Dropbox wizard started, I supplied my second user's email address, the wizard downloaded the Dropbox daemon and then downloaded the appropriate folders & their contents to the Dropbox folder. Everything is now OK for Dropbox.